# Debugging Python File in monorepo in VS Code gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using:

- VS Code v1.74.3
- ms-python.python v2022.20.2
- python v3.9.1 (installed globally with Pyenv)

**My setup**

```bash
workspace-root
└── dir-1
└── dir-2
    └── src
        └── event_producer_1
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── main.py
            └── schemas
                └── cloud_event
                    └── schema
                        └── my_org
                            └── cloud_event
                                ├── MyEvent.py
                                ├── __init__.py
                                └── marshaller.py
```

For context, everything under the path `workspace-root/dir-2/src/event_producer_1/schemas/cloud_event/` has been generated from a schema stored in AWS Eventbridge's Schema Registry using the [code binding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-schema-code-bindings.html) feature.

The `workspace-root/dir-2/src/event_producer_1/schemas/cloud_event/schema/my_org/cloud_event/__init__.py` file looks like this:

```py
# coding: utf-8

from __future__ import absolute_import

from schema.my_org.cloud_event.marshaller import Marshaller # <-- Error thrown here whilst debugging in VS Code
from schema.my_org.cloud_event.MyEvent import MyEvent
```

And the `workspace-root/dir-2/src/event_producer_1/main.py` file looks like this:

```py
import boto3
from schemas.cloud_event.schema.my_org.cloud_event import Marshaller, MyEvent

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    data = Marshaller().unmarshall(event, MyEvent)
```

My `launch.json` file looks like this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/dir-2/src/event_producer_1"},
        }
    ]
}
```

**The problem**

When I try to debug the `main.py` file, I get the following error on the line indicated in the `__init__.py` file above:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'schema'

The code debug's fine in PyCharm which leads me to believe it's a configuration issue with VS Code.

Comment: and another one. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423857/11107541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `.env` file under the workspace:

```
PYTHONPATH=PATH/TO/cloud_event
```

Then add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
```